# local action behavior differs based on where variables are defined

Tags: ansible

I wrote two roles, one which installs OpenSSH on a remote server, and another which installs some Windows features on the same server. The first role runs with WinRM. Once the first role is finished (and OpenSSH is installed), the second role is executed with SSH.

install-openssh.yml:

```
---
- name: Install and configure OpenSSH
  hosts: all
  vars:
    ansible_user: ansible
    ansible_password: "{{ server_password }}"
    ansible_connection: winrm
    ansible_port: 5985
  roles:
    - install-openssh
```

install-wfeature.yml:

```
---
- name: Install Windows features
  hosts: all
  vars:
    ansible_user: ansible
    ansible_connection: ssh
    ansible_port: 22
  roles:
    - install-wfeature
```

My current problem is that in each role I have certain tasks that are delegated to the controller node (with `local_action`). However, if executed as it is, I get the following error message:

```
<localhost> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible on PORT 5985 to localhost
fatal: [target_server -> localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "plaintext: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5985): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fdb8b10bb20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

One might say the configuration is wrong but if I move the variables to `roles/install-openssh/defaults/main.yml` and `roles/install-wfeature/defaults/main.yml` respectively, then the first playbook (i.e., install-openssh) succeeds, and it seems that the connection for delegated tasks is established differently:

```
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: gitlab-runner
```

The user `gitlab-runner` is simply the user that runs our GitLab pipelines on the controller node.

The second playbook, however, fails with a similar error message to the first case:

```
<localhost> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
[...]
fatal: [target_server -> localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Data could not be sent to remote host \"localhost\". Make sure this host can be reached over ssh: Host key verification failed.\r\n",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

To be clear, any other tasks that are not delegated to localhost run successfully, so the host is in fact reachable. I do not understand why the delegation fails and why the establishment of the connection to localhost differs based on where the variables are defined even though the values are identical anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Set the variable *`ansible_connection: local`* in the tasks either running on the *localhost* or delegated to the *localhost*. Anywhere in the [vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable), you can declare the variable either statically

```yaml
ansible_connection: localhost
```

or dynamically

```yaml
ansible_connection: "{{ (ansible_host)|d(inventory_hostname) == 'localhost')|
                        ternary('local', 'ssh') }}"
```

In your case, you might want to try the playbooks

```yaml
---
- name: Install and configure OpenSSH
  hosts: all
  vars:
    ansible_user: ansible
    ansible_password: "{{ server_password }}"
    ansible_port: 5985
    ansible_connection: "{{ (ansible_host|d(inventory_hostname) == 'localhost')|
                             ternary('local', 'winrm') }}"
  roles:
    - install-openssh
```

```yaml
---
- name: Install Windows features
  hosts: all
  vars:
    ansible_user: ansible
    ansible_port: 22
    ansible_connection: "{{ (ansible_host|d(inventory_hostname) == 'localhost'|
                             ternary('local', 'ssh') }}"
  roles:
    - install-wfeature
```

---

- Optionally, you can test the membership in a list. For example,

```yaml
  c_names: [localhost, 127.0.0.1]
  ansible_connection: "{{ (ansible_host|d(inventory_hostname) in c_names)|
                          ternary('local', 'ssh') }}"
```

- If you want to always use *winrm* to connect to the controller keep the first playbook as is and change the second one

```yaml
- name: Install Windows features
  hosts: all
  vars:
    ansible_user: ansible
    ansible_port: 22
    ansible_connection: "{{ (ansible_host|d(inventory_hostname) == 'localhost'|
                             ternary('winrm', 'ssh') }}"
  roles:
    - install-wfeature
```

---

Details: There are many options on how to declare the variable *ansible_connection*. For example,
given the inventory for testing

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[test]
test_11
test_13

[test:vars]
ansible_user=admin
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3.8
```

1. Set the variable *`ansible_connection: ssh`* in the playbook and [override](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) it by *`ansible_connection: local`* in the block that is delegated to the localhost *`delegate_to: localhost`*

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: test

  vars:

    ansible_connection: ssh
    ansible_port: 22

  tasks:

    - command: uname -o
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout

    - block:
        - command: uname -o
          register: out
        - debug:
            var: out.stdout
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      vars:
        ansible_connection: local
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [test_11]
changed: [test_13]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_13] => 
  out.stdout: FreeBSD
ok: [test_11] => 
  out.stdout: FreeBSD

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [test_11 -> localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11 -> localhost] => 
  out.stdout: GNU/Linux
```

---

2. You can put the [connection variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/connection_details.html#connection-methods-and-details) into the inventory and remove them from the playbook. For example, the playbook below gives the same results

```ini
shell> cat hosts
localhost ansible_connection=local

[test]
test_11
test_13

[test:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_port=22
ansible_user=admin
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3.8
```

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: test

  tasks:

    - command: uname -o
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout

    - block:
        - command: uname -o
          register: out
        - debug:
            var: out.stdout
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

---

3. Declare the variable dynamically depending on the host

The [test](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#list-of-builtin-tests) below utilizes the fact that the value of the variable *ansible_host* is set to the name of the host the task is delegated to

```yaml
  c_names: [localhost, 127.0.0.1]
  ansible_connection: "{{ (ansible_host|d(inventory_hostname) in c_names)|
                          ternary('local', 'ssh') }}"
```

3a) The inventory and the playbook below test the delegation

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[test]
test_11
test_13

[test:vars]
ansible_user=admin
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3.8
```

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: test

  vars:

    c_names: [localhost, 127.0.0.1]
    ansible_connection: "{{ (ansible_host|d(inventory_hostname) in c_names)|
                            ternary('local', 'ssh') }}"
    ansible_port: 22

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          inventory_hostname: {{ inventory_hostname }}
          ansible_host: {{ ansible_host|d(inventory_hostname) }}
          in c_names: {{ inventory_hostname in c_names }}
          ansible_connection: {{ ansible_connection }}
    - command: uname -o
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout

    - block:
        - debug:
            msg: |
              inventory_hostname: {{ inventory_hostname }}
              ansible_host: {{ ansible_host }}
              in c_names: {{ ansible_host in c_names }}
              ansible_connection: {{ ansible_connection }}
        - command: uname -o
          register: out
        - debug:
            var: out.stdout
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true

    - block:
        - debug:
            msg: |
              inventory_hostname: {{ inventory_hostname }}
              ansible_host: {{ ansible_host }}
              in c_names: {{ ansible_host in c_names }}
              ansible_connection: {{ ansible_connection }}
        - command: uname -o
          register: out
        - debug:
            var: out.stdout
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

PLAY [test] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_13] => 
  msg: |-
    inventory_hostname: test_13
    ansible_host: test_13
    in c_names: False
    ansible_connection: ssh
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: |-
    inventory_hostname: test_11
    ansible_host: test_11
    in c_names: False
    ansible_connection: ssh

TASK [command] ********************************************************************************
changed: [test_11]
changed: [test_13]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  out.stdout: FreeBSD
ok: [test_13] => 
  out.stdout: FreeBSD

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11 -> localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    inventory_hostname: test_11
    ansible_host: localhost
    in c_names: True
    ansible_connection: local

TASK [command] ********************************************************************************
changed: [test_11 -> localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11 -> localhost] => 
  out.stdout: GNU/Linux

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11 -> 127.0.0.1] => 
  msg: |-
    inventory_hostname: test_11
    ansible_host: 127.0.0.1
    in c_names: True
    ansible_connection: local

TASK [command] ********************************************************************************
changed: [test_11 -> 127.0.0.1]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11 -> 127.0.0.1] => 
  out.stdout: GNU/Linux

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
test_11: ok=9    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

3b) Test the simpler option where localhost is a member of *groups.all*

```ini
shell> cat hosts
localhost

[test]
test_11
test_13

[test:vars]
ansible_user=admin
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3.8
```

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    c_names: [localhost, 127.0.0.1]
    ansible_connection: "{{ (ansible_host|d(inventory_hostname) in c_names)|
                            ternary('local', 'ssh') }}"
    ansible_port: 22

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          inventory_hostname: {{ inventory_hostname }}
          ansible_host: {{ ansible_host|d(inventory_hostname) }}
          in c_names: {{ ansible_host|d(inventory_hostname) in c_names }}
          ansible_connection: {{ ansible_connection }}
    - command: uname -o
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: |-
    inventory_hostname: test_11
    ansible_host: test_11
    in c_names: False
    ansible_connection: ssh
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    inventory_hostname: localhost
    ansible_host: localhost
    in c_names: True
    ansible_connection: local
ok: [test_13] => 
  msg: |-
    inventory_hostname: test_13
    ansible_host: test_13
    in c_names: False
    ansible_connection: ssh

TASK [command] ********************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]
changed: [test_11]
changed: [test_13]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  out.stdout: GNU/Linux
ok: [test_11] => 
  out.stdout: FreeBSD
ok: [test_13] => 
  out.stdout: FreeBSD

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_11: ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

3c) The above playbook will also work with the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
controller ansible_host=127.0.0.1

[test]
test_11
test_13

[test:vars]
ansible_user=admin
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3.8
```

---

3d) You can put the variables into the inventory and remove them from the playbook. The inventory and the playbook below will give the same results

```ini
shell> cat hosts
localhost

[test]
test_11
test_13

[test:vars]
ansible_user=admin
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3.8

[all:vars]
c_names=[localhost, 127.0.0.1]
ansible_connection="{{ (ansible_host|d(inventory_hostname) in c_names)|ternary('local', 'ssh') }}"
ansible_port=22
```

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          inventory_hostname: {{ inventory_hostname }}
          ansible_host: {{ ansible_host|d(inventory_hostname) }}
          in c_names: {{ ansible_host|d(inventory_hostname) in c_names }}
          ansible_connection: {{ ansible_connection }}
    - command: uname -o
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout
```

---

See:

- [Running against localhost](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/connection_details.html#running-against-localhost)
- [Index of all Connection Plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index_connection.html)

---

Q: ***"Setting *`ansible_connection: local`* as a variable in delegated tasks seems to fix the issue. But I do not understand why. According to this [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html), this is set implicitly, so why do I need to override it explicitly?"***

A: You're missing one [detail](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html#implicit-localhost). Quoting:

> You can override the built-in implicit version by creating a localhost host entry in your inventory.

In other words, when you put *localhost* into the inventory the implicit connection *local* doesn't work anymore. Let's test it. The [default connection plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-transport) is *smart*. Quoting:

> Default connection plugin to use, the ‘smart’ option will toggle between ‘ssh’ and ‘paramiko’ depending on controller OS and ssh versions

```ini
shell> ansible-config dump | grep DEFAULT_TRANSPORT
DEFAULT_TRANSPORT(default) = smart
```

Given the inventory below for testing

```ini
shell> cat hosts
localhost ansible_user=admin
test_11 ansible_user=admin
```

Run the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml 
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - stat: path=/tmp
```

with the option `-vvvv` to enable connection debugging and grep the connection. You can see that *ssh* was used to connect both *localhost* and remote host

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -vvvv -i hosts playbook.yml | grep ESTABLISH
<localhost> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
<test_11> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
<localhost> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
<test_11> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
<localhost> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
```

Test the delegation to *localhost*

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - stat: path=/tmp
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

The delegation to localhost didn't result in implicit connection *local* because *localhost* is in the inventory

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -vvvv -i hosts playbook.yml | grep ESTABLISH
<localhost> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
<localhost> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
<localhost> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
```

Let's remove *localhost* from the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
test_11 ansible_user=admin
```

and run the playbook again. The implicit connection *local* works as expected

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -vvvv -i hosts playbook.yml | grep ESTABLISH
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
```

Comment: Setting `ansible_connection: local` as a variable in delegated tasks seems to fix the issue. But I do not understand why! :D According to [this documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html), this is set implicitly, so why do I need to override it explicitly?

Comment: I added the explanation.